# Metaphorisches Äquivalent für „zwischen zwei Stühlen sitzen“

Tags: regional, phrase-request, proverb

Die Redewendung *zwischen zwei Stühlen sitzen* bedeutet, dass jemand zwischen zwei Möglichkeiten wählen muss, und am Ende keine bekommt.

Zum Beispiel:

- wenn man einen Arbeitsvertrag wegen eines besseren Angebots kündigt, das man aber letztlich auch nicht bekommt.
- wenn jemand in einer Beziehung untreu ist, und letzlich verliert beide Partner.

Was es für mich ganz interessant macht: Kein Deutscher, dem ich es bisher gesagt habe, hat diese Redewendung verstanden, obwohl es viele Ergebnisse auf Google liefert.

- Warum ist es (in Nordbayern) praktisch unbekannt?
- Was könnte ich statt dessen sagen?
- Es scheint mir eine rückwirkende Konstruktion zu sein. Deswegen hätte ich es ohne Google als *sich zwischen zwei Stühlen setzen* formuliert. Aber das ist wahrscheinlich falsch (oder liefert kaum Ergebnisse auf Google), warum?

Comment: Für die beschriebenen Fälle käme noch [*verschlimmbessern*](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/verschlimmbessern) in Frage.

Comment: Ein *Sprichwort* ist das sicher nicht - ersetzen durch *Redewendung*?

Comment: @guidot Ja, ich tue es. Danke!

Comment: Mir völlig unbekannt, warum sie in Franken unbekannt sein soll … in Bayern müsste sie bekannt sein. Werd ich aber mal ausprobieren ;)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

***Zwischen zwei Stühlen sitzen*** bedeutet, eine Entscheidung fällen zu müssen, die in jedem Fall dazu führt, einen Nachteil in Kauf nehmen zu müssen. Ein anderer Begriff ist *[Zwickmühle](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zwickm%C3%BChle_(M%C3%BChlespiel))*.

Sie bedeutet *nicht*, sich zwischen zwei Dingen entscheiden zu müssen, um am Ende keine der Optionen zu bekommen.

Häufig benutzt man die Redewendung im Bezug auf persönliche Beziehungen, aber auch andere Fälle sind möglich.

Beispiel:
Ich liebe meinen Mann und meine Mutter. Leider können sich die beiden nicht ausstehen.

- Ich könnte an Weihnachten mit meinem Mann verreisen, dann wäre er glücklich, meine Mutter unglücklich.
- Oder ich könnte Weihnachten bei meiner Mutter feiern, was meinen Mann unglücklich machen würde.

Man könnte die Redewendung dahingehend abwandeln, dass man das „sich in eine solche Situation bringen“ als „sich zwischen zwei Stühle setzen“ bezeichnet, ob sie verstanden wird, hängt vom Zuhörer ab.

Answer (score 4):

Da das Sprichwort schon wunderbar von Stephie erklärt wurde, würde ich gerne auf deine zwei Beispiele eingehen.
Zumindest für den sächsischen Raum kann ich mit Sicherheit sagen, dass dies typische Fälle für diese Redewendung sind:

> Wie man es macht, macht man es falsch.

Der größte Unterschied besteht darin, dass man sich in diesem Fall schon bei den Konsequenzen befindet, wobei bei *zwischen zwei Stühlen sitzen* noch keine Entscheidung getroffen wurde.
Diese beiden Sprichworte haben auch nicht wirklich etwas miteinander zu tun. (siehe hier noch einmal Stephies Erklärung)
Für deine Beispiele befindet man sich im Grundzustand in einer annehmbaren oder guten Situation und der **Versuch** etwas verbessern (oder allgemein ändern) zu wollen endet mit dem denkbar schlimmsten Ausgang. Beim gefragten Sprichwort hingegen **muss** man sich **gegen** etwas enscheiden und die negativen Auswirkungen sind gewissermaßen unabdingbar.